# Categorical Quotients and Group Actions on Varities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions

So I am given that

Let $G = Z/dZ$ where d ≥ 1. Let w be a generator for G and let
G act on $A^
{n+1}$ via
$w(x_{0}, . . . , x_{n})$ = $(wx_{0}, . . . , wx_{n})$.

How can I Show that the
categorical quotient of $A^{n+1}$ by G is the affine cone over the projective
variety $ν_{d}(P^
{n}) ⊂ P^
{\begin{pmatrix}n+d\\d\end{pmatrix}}$
.

Comment: Since this is your assignment, can you at least share what you tried ?

Comment: Couldn't really make any headway! I can't figure out how to approach it even though it looks fairly simple.

Comment: OK. Let's hope someone helps.

Answer (score 1):

First off: what is the affine cone here? $v_d(\mathbb P^n)$ is the image of all monomials of degree $d$ in $n+1$ variables. So the affine cone is $Y = \mathrm{Spec}k[x^I]$, where $x^I$ ranges through all monomials of degree $d$.

According to Wikipedia, we have to check two things. First, that $Y$ is invariant under $G$, and secondly that any invariant morphism from $\mathbb A^n$ to another variety $Z$ factors through $Y$.

The first condition is clear, since the action is given by multiplying the coordinates by a $d$'th rooth of unity.

Now we have to show that given an invariant morphism, it must factor through $Y$. We can assume that $Z$ is affine, and hence that $Z=\mathbb A^m$ for some $m$. This further reduces to $ Z = \mathbb A^1$. Hence we are reduced to showing that any invariant polynomial belongs to the coordinate ring of $Y$, that is
$$
k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^G = k[X^I].
$$

The inclusion $\supseteq$ is clear. On the other hand, suppose $f(x)$ is homogeneous and invariant under $G$. We only need to show that the degree of $f$ is a multiple of $d$. Note that a polynomial is homogeneous of degree $d$ if and only if $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^d f(x)$ for all $\lambda \in k^\ast$. But since $f$ is invariant under $G$, we have
$$
f(x)=f(\omega x) = \omega^{deg f} f(x).
$$
This implies that $d \mid deg f$, as wanted.